# AngularJS $http service

Tags: angularjs

I call `$http` services in AngularJS to fetch JSON but I always get a

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

This is the code I'm using:

```
app.controller('activeUserController', function($scope,$http) {
     $http({
               method: "GET",
               url: /url,
               success: function (response) {
            },
            failure: function (response) {
               alert(response.d);
            }});
}
```

Comment: error 500 should come from your server so check there or post the code

Comment: There is an error in your syntax. If /url is rly your url, you should put it in quotes. If url is a variable, you should remove the /

Comment: What kind of technology/framework do you use for server side?

Comment: hello  #Guinn , i actually using the same with jquery so i think its not an url passing issue & #Eylen using jquery i am able to get the json,so pls tell me what should i do.  & #Discosultan actually i am not getting you please clarify.

Comment: #Guinn i use url that mentioned here:    url: "http://oasischat.phonegap.webstagesite.com/chatapp.asmx/ActiveUserNotification?SecretKey=" + scretKey + "&Receiver_ID=" + localStorage.getItem("UserID"),

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error means your API code is throwing exception. So the issue is on back end not front end.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to you that you check the api get method.

Comment: That is not an answer. It's a comment.